# Kicad Footprint Validation Conflict

Tags: rf, kicad, footprint

I am trying to create a simple SMA connector footprint in Kicad but whenever I try to save the footprint to a library, Kicad generates a "validation conflict" error. I have no visibility into the nature of the error. Can anyone suggest how I can figure out what's going on?

Comment: Can you show more details about the error and what the footprint looks like?

Comment: if you push the check footprint button does it says something?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the presence of spaces in my footprint name. Once I replaced them with underscores, the error message was resolved -_-